# How Jersey extracts generic type from Collections to invoke javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter#writeTo()?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, jersey

In a Rest Service using the JAX-RS specification, I can define a generic service like

```
@GET
@Path("something")
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<MyPojo> getMyPojoList() {
    ...
}
```

Something magic happens in Jersey because when invoking

```
javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter#writeTo(T t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation annotations[], 
        MediaType mediaType, 
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException;
```

when analyzing the `genericType` it is easy to see that his value is `class MyPojo`.

I've been trying to read the Jersey source code to understand how they extract the Collection Generic type of before invoking the method `writeTo` of `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter`, but I got lost once arrived to read the `GenericEntity` class.

Can anyone help me to understand which kind of magic they use there? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Some generic information is retained through the compiler into runtime.  Take a look at the documentation on Java reflection.  In this case they probably use [getGenericReturnType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType%28%29), although there are a host of methods relating to parameter types and even the class's generic parameters.

The most obvious shortcoming here is that only information from compile time may be kept - in particular you cannot reliably inspect a List to determine whether it is a `List<Integer>` or `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the magical classes of the JAX-RS framework to preserve the information you're looking for. Took me quite some time to actually get this working on my project as well, but this is how I solved the problem:

First, inside your Resource class, pass the generic collection as such (note I use Response Objects):

```
public Response findAll() {
  Collection<MyType> entities = service.findAll(); // whatever code you need to load it.
  GenericEntity<Collection<MyType>> list = new GenericEntity<Collection<MyType>>(entities) {}; // This line is key!
  return Response.ok.entity(list).build();
}
```

Then you can create a normal *MessageBodyWriter* implementation and perform the type-checking in the method that is responsible for checking whether your implementation is suitable or not.

```
public class MyTypeMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<MyType> {
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type) && genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
            Type[] actualTypeArgs = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
            return (actualTypeArgs.length == 1 && actualTypeArgs[0].equals(MyType.class));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can enhance the `isWriteable` method to perform more checks like double check whether the `MediaType` is the correct one for example, and if some annotations need to be present etc, depending on your requirements.

But to summerize:

- Wrap your collection in the `GenericEntity<>` wrapper to preserver generic type info
- Perform the proper casts inside the MessageBodyWriter to determine the type.

Comment: Once `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type)` is `true`, do we still need to check `actualTypeArgs.length == 1`?